# DrawingBrush with transperancy

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create `DrawingBrush` with transparency and could not figure out on how-to set this transparency :( Here is the XAML:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Yellow" Background="Green">
        <Rectangle>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <DrawingBrush>
                    <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                        <DrawingGroup>
                            <GeometryDrawing Brush="Red">
                                <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                    <CombinedGeometry GeometryCombineMode="Exclude">
                                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 110, 110" />
                                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry1>
                                        <CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                            <RectangleGeometry Rect="10, 10, 90, 90" />
                                        </CombinedGeometry.Geometry2>
                                    </CombinedGeometry>
                                </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                    <Pen Brush="Blue" Thickness=".3" />
                                </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            </GeometryDrawing>
                        </DrawingGroup>
                    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
                </DrawingBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
    </Border>
```

The output is:

[image: output]

1. `<GeometryDrawing Brush="Red">`
2. `<Border Background="Green">`

How I could set the background color of the brush to `Transparent` ?

*If I set it in XAML (`GeometryDrawing Brush="Transparent"`) then brush will get the background color from upper control `Border` and everything will be Green color*

The main idea is draw `Rectangle` in the **middle** of control/Brush

Comment: I'm a little confused what you expect the end result to be. You want the green part to be completely transparent?

Comment: @vcsjones The `Red` part

Comment: You put a Rectange with a (partly) transparent Fill in a Border with a green Background. Of course you'll see the green Background through the transparent part. What is your expectation? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Clemens - I'm trying to draw a `Rectangle` with color in the middle of control. The space from `Rectangle` to outer border (the red color) should be transparent.

Comment: @Clemens  I don't understand the question.... I need to set a color of `Rectangle` - how ? I set a `Background` brush of `Border` - this `DrawingBrush` paint it only in inner `Rectangle` and set all the 'red' area to Transparent. This is the idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment:

> DrawingBrush paint it only in inner Rectangle and set all the 'red' area to Transparent

That's not how the rendering model in WPF works. When you declare in XAML the things you want drawn, you are describing a collection of objects to be rendered. A color that is transparent (i.e. has alpha value of 0, like the built-in `Transparent` value) doesn't "set" the pixels under it to be transparent; it simply doesn't render *itself*. Using transparent colors in an object simply reveals whatever is under that object.

If you want to draw, inside your border, a green box which is itself bordered by transparent pixels, then you need to not fill the border at all (because that will show through transparent pixels), and you need to define a `Drawing` that draws exactly what you want. I.e. a transparent rectangle to define the actual extents of the desired rectangle, and then a smaller filled rectangle inside of that.

For example:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO33761293InsetRectangleBorder.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="525" Width="525">

  <Window.Resources>
    <DrawingBrush x:Key="drawingBrush1">
      <DrawingBrush.Drawing>
        <DrawingGroup>
          <GeometryDrawing Brush="Green">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <RectangleGeometry Rect="10, 10, 90, 90" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
              <Pen Brush="Blue" Thickness=".3" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
          </GeometryDrawing>
          <GeometryDrawing Brush="Transparent">
            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
              <RectangleGeometry Rect="0, 0, 110, 110" />
            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
          </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
      </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    </DrawingBrush>
  </Window.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="1">
      <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource drawingBrush1}"/>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I must be confusing everyone here :( After searching a lot at Google I understand that I need to look at `OpacityMask` Something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743320(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_6    but your answer exactly on my question. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you can use `OpacityMask` as well. Please note, however, that the same basic issue will apply: the `OpacityMask` affects _only_ the object on which it's been set. For example, in the above you could have just a single green rectangle in the brush, but apply an opacity mask that sets the outer ten-pixel border to transparent. But you'll still need to apply this mask to the `Rectangle`, and it still won't affect anything drawn under the `Rectangle` (i.e. other than letting it show through).